# Список названий в Alert сообщении на Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Здравствуйте! Пробую сделать календарь, где нажимая на число, появляется Alert окно с сообщением события на этот день. Но если событий на этот день несколько, то хотелось бы выводить список из названий событий, чтобы нажимая на названия, была возможность перейти на другой контроллер для прочтения выбранного события. Может кто сталкивался, как выводить список в Alert окнах и реально ли это вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я правда в obj-c делал так , это не совсем список,но отражается как список.

```
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Добрый день"
                                                  message:@"Кому вы собираетесь позвонить"
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Закрыть окно"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Секриториат", @"Юридическим лицам", @"Физическим лицам", nil];
[message show];
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ты делаешь календарь для iPad используй popover с таблицей. 
Если для iPhone/iPod я бы, на твоем месте, презентовал таблицу. Т.к в дальнейшем этот список может составлять больше чем из 3-4 элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал `UIActionSheet` если iOS < 8,
иначе `UIAlertController`.